# MS-Access2016 database does not show SQL View

Tags: ms-access-2016

I was given an Access2016 database to make some changes to and was trying to get the SQL View of a query, but that option is not available.

All my searching on the internet pretty reveals that SQL View is not available for "web databases".

So, how do I verify that the database is a "web database" and if so, how to convert to a "standard" database or is there a way to get SQL View back?

Comment: What is the file extension? accdb, accde, or something else?

Comment: the extension is accdb

Comment: Is there a way to convert from the "web database" to "normal" database?

Comment: You should be able to open the query in design view, correct? What does it say when you check your server location or database name, with the File tab > Info.

Comment: Didn't realize Access Web Apps were being phased out. Link here on pulling data back into Access https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-access-web-app-tables-to-an-access-desktop-database-09a7de29-cee8-4025-b985-7a78dffdb005

Comment: I was able to follow the export/import vba code in this article to get all the objects out of the web database to a standard database and now I have access to the SQL View of queries and everything else.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_mobile/convert-web-access-database-to-normal-access/1b27f596-91e8-4d47-86ad-1ea5ffea088f